# Using python to treat a .txt file as a large string, and iterate over each {} in the file

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7, for-loop

I have a data.txt and a count.py.

My data in data.txt looks something like this:

```
hermione [
  {
   keyword.adsf
   keyword.bsdf
  },
  {
   keyword.1sdf
   keyword.bsd
   keyword.bsd
  }
  ]
ron [
  {
   keyword.adsf
   keyword.bsdf
  },
  {
   keyword.1sdf
   keyword.bsd
   keyword.bsd
  }
  ]
```

What I want to do is count the number of `keyword.xxx` occurrences inside each {} using python. In other words, I want my output to be like this:

```
hermione [
  {
   2
  },
  {
   3
  }
  ]
ron [
  {
   2
  },
  {
   3
  }
  ]
```

I was thinking that in count.py, I would write the script to make the counts, and treat data.txt as a large string.

So far this is the code that I've written:

```
from sys import argv
script, filename = argv
txt = open(filename).read()
def count_in_bracket():
    print txt
print count_in_bracket()
```

(I run python `custom_fields_nocount.py custom_fields_nocount.txt` in the terminal.)

... which isn't much, since it doesn't iterate through each {} bracket.

That's the part I have trouble figuring out. How do I write something like

```
list = ['ron', 'hermione']
for {} in list:
    print len(CONTENTS_OF_EACH_{}.split("keyword"))-1
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular expressions, you could do:

```
import re

contents_of_each = re.findall('{([^}]+?)}', txt, re.DOTALL)
```

this would give you a list with every string between `{}`

How it works: it searches an open curly, then a sequence of one or more characters that are not a close curly, then a close curly, but return only what is inside the parentheses.

`re.DOTALL` treats newlines as regular characters, matching curly pairs that span many lines.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I didn't really see how your answer could have been used, at first, but then I realized:                                     for item in contents_of_each:
 print len(item.split("keyword"))-1

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it with pure Python.  This might be handy if you need more complex processing rather than just counting things.

```
import sys

def prn(s):
    sys.stdout.write(str(s))

def _parse_list(f, line):
    if line.strip() != '{':
        raise ValueError("list part must start with '{'")
    prn(line)

    count = 0
    found_list_end = False
    for line in f:
        if line.strip().startswith('}'):
            found_list_end = True
            break
        count += 1
    if not found_list_end:
        raise ValueError("list part must end with '}'")
    prn("    {}\n".format(count))
    prn(line)


def parse_section(f):
    found_section_start = False
    for line in f:
        prn(line)
        words = line.split()
        if len(words) == 2 and words[1] == '[':
            found_section_start = True
            break
    if not found_section_start:
        return False  

    for line in f:
        if line.strip() == ']':
            prn(line)
            return True
        _parse_list(f, line)
    return True

with open("data.txt", "rt") as f:
    while parse_section(f):
        pass
```